# URL change in HTTPS automatically

Tags: wordpress, url, https

Test URL = https://www.uktherapyhub.co.uk/info.php
Code is below

```
<?php include 'wp-load.php'; ?>
<a href="http://adrianmatthewstherapy.co.uk">http://adrianmatthewstherapy.co.uk</a>
```

Above is my code why it is adding the s in after http?

If i remove wp-load,php it works fine.

Comment: can you share wp-config.php? (make sure to hide your database name and login credentials)

Comment: Here is - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-4mZq_a9ymh23ix6NOtvXNbN1Xy-nf8Z/view?usp=sharing

Comment: wp-config does not include any https configuration, must be your htaccess, can you share it as well?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vlryY5Hn9S9_h-UG7KZrK2zPirxeYNCy/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This may be some JavaScript that add S in when page render on browser

Answer (score 0):

There's a chance server is programmed to redirect all http requests to https. You have to change server (adrianmatthewstherapy) configuration to allow http request and not redirect them.

Comment: I don't think there's any way a hardcoded link can be changed to https

Comment: URL is only changed when it comes in WordPress environment. If i removed wp-load.php it will work fine. There must be issue in WordPress or any of my Plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If website is configured for HTTPS, you might need to change the other links to follow the secure connection. Specially I've observed google chrome (Version 80.0.3987.122) is converting all the internal links (audio src) to https.

A good reading: 
https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/6286127?hl=en